# Rails 4 site-wide filter records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it somehow possible to filter database records site wide? My models are `league`, `match`,  `team`, `player` and `detail`. Now I would like when I enter the site and select a `league` that everything on the site is only displaying data for this specific `league`.

My relations are:

```ruby
league has_many matches
match belongs_to team1
match belongs_to team2
team has_many players
player has_many details
```

Would that be possible?

Comment: This question is too broad to answer in such form, but you may want to read about [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: But nested resources is only for displaying something like /league/id/matches, I mean I want to click on the matches link and then it should only show matches for a given league. I was thinking about something like a `before_filter` that applies to every query I do.

Comment: For the sake of having canonical urls you should really avoid "magic" and go for directly specifying league in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

---

**Principle**

If the `league` option is going to be the main decider of the content on your app, you might want to design *around* the `league` model

To do this, you'd make your `root` the league controller, and then show data based on the `league`'s associated content

I.E instead of `Team.joins(:league).where(league: "x")`, you would do:

```
#Leagues
league = League.find(x)
league.matches
```

This would mean you could load the league directly from the database, making it much simpler for the user

---

**Nested Resources**

The alternative to this is to use the [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) method that Michael Szyndel recommended in his comment. This would make it so you'd have to visit the URLs as follows:

```
domain.com/leagues/1/matches/2/teams/1
```

The benefit of this would be to DRY up your code, but it would add lots of extra levels to your system, which you may not want. I'll give an overview of what I'd look at below:

---

**Code**

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "leagues#index"

#app/controllers/leagues_controller.rb
def index
    league = params[:league] ? params[:league] : "0"
    @league = League.find(league)
end

#app/views/league/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag('/') do %>
     <%= select_tag 'league', options_for_select(League.all.collect {|u| [u.name, u.id] }) %>
<% end %>

<% @league.matches.each do |match| %>
    <%= "#{match.team_1.name} vs #{match.team_2.name} : #{match.created_at}" %>
<% end %>
```

This would need to be re-factored & extended to include match details, make the "league" a session variable etc, but as the question might be closed, I thought I'd give you some ideas

The bottom line is that it comes down to how you want the app to function

Comment: can you please check my comment to Michael Szyndels response?

Comment: Thought as much! You'd need to use [Session Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) - do you want me to write some codE?

Comment: I have already set a `before_filter` inside my `application_controller`, which gets the current `league` as `@current_league` do I now have to add this variable to every action inside my other controllers for the queries?

Comment: Yes, but there should be a DRYer way to do it

Comment: Thats what I am looking for, so I dont have to add this variable to every controller.

Comment: Ohhh right - you might want to check this Q/A out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342470/rails-3-best-way-to-handle-nested-resource-queries-in-your-controllers

Comment: I also think, one of my problems is, I cant say for example `league.teams` because a `match` has two `teams` associated with foreign keys. And these two teams have to be specific, like for example black_team and white_team, do you think it would be better to have a join table for that and remove the two foreign keys from my match table?